# signTransaction() wallet adapter

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, anchor-client, blockhash

```
const {signTransaction} = useWallet()

const transaction = new Transaction()

const tx = .... //arbitrary anchor program method as transaction

transaction.add(tx)

const signature =  signTransaction(transaction) //errors out
```

How does the signTransaction() function from the wallet adapter work?

https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/packages/core/react/src/useWallet.ts

It says it takes a transaction and returns a promise but when I try to use it I get the following error.

```
WalletSignTransactionError: Transaction recentBlockhash required
at PhantomWalletAdapter.signTransaction
```

I know I can send my transaction a different way but I want to get a signed transaction object without sending it.

Comment: You dont get the signature when you use the signTransaction function it gives you the signed tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a `Transaction` object without sending it, it is required to set `recentBlockhash` and `feePayer` fields like so:

```
const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
transaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
```

and only then sign the transaction. `recentBlockchash` is used to check by Solana whether the transaction is outdated. If, for example, you sign a transaction but send it after 5 minutes, that transaction will be rejected and you will need to resign. This is why it is part of the transaction object.

I had the same issue in the [Place | Solana](http://solana-place.com/) project. [Here is](https://github.com/serejke/solana-place/blob/9cdd214daa0759afb585c03d3a75af750ef89298/server/src/service/TransactionBuilderService.ts#L20) how I create a transaction on the server, send the serialized transaction to client who [signs](https://github.com/serejke/solana-place/blob/6599635534955a6e104c0ba6bd41907ff100ffa9/client/src/request/changePixels.ts#L29) it and forwards to the server for [sending](https://github.com/serejke/solana-place/blob/9cdd214daa0759afb585c03d3a75af750ef89298/server/src/service/TransactionService.ts#L17).